# grouping by weekly break down of datetimes 64 python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime64

I have a pandas data frame with a column that represents dates as:

```
Name: ts_placed, Length: 13631, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

It looks like this:

```
0    2014-10-18 16:53:00
1    2014-10-27 11:57:00
2    2014-10-27 11:57:00
3    2014-10-08 16:35:00
4    2014-10-24 16:36:00
5    2014-11-06 15:34:00
6    2014-11-11 10:30:00
....
```

I know how to group it in general using the function:

```
grouped = data.groupby('ts_placed')
```

What I want to do is to use the same function but to group the rows by week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date).week
```

as the argument to `groupby`. This is the ordinal week in the year; see [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) for other definitions of week.

Comment: it works. just one more thing. the output is <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x10f23a588> do you know how can I see it? sorry for the nooby question but I can't find it anyway.

Comment: Oh, you need to refer to the [`groupby` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). Groupby is just a step - you need to do something with the result, e.g., `df.groupby(...).mean()`. I really suggest you read the docs.

Comment: once I have grouped them how do I save them as separated datasets?

Comment: You mean to separate files? That's a legitimate question, but I really think it's a separate one. It's not that easy to converse via these comments.

Comment: I'll ask one more question then. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Timergrouper

```
df.set_index(your_date).groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).size()
```